# Are questions about items for collecting on topic?

Tags: discussion, scope

I am not sure whether "collecting" is the appropriate word. What I mean is getting something mainly for the sake of having/displaying it, not using it. This question was triggered by a recent rifle question (that looks like a collectible to me, but might not be - no expert there). However I believe there is a broader point here, e.g. knives, old ice axes, ... may be collected. They were used in the outdoors, but the act of collecting those isn't obviously outdoorsy.

Do we want questions about collecting outdoor-related items?

The obvious examples are "How/Where can I obtain XY?", but it might also be something like "How many Xs of type Y do still exist/are still usable?".

Comment: Tools potentially, ammo possibly, but within reason - I guess it will all depend on the wording. "What kind of screwdriver can unscrew this screw on this outdoor item" vs "Where can I get a screwdriver for this weird screw from" or another example "Should I still use X even if it's old/not many left" vs "Where can I get X because it's old and awesome"

Comment: Personally I would say it's off topic. To ask for what's the best option for an outdoor equipment is vastly different from asking where one can buy for display purposes. Even knives, axes et al when spoken in terms of antiques would make no sense in TGO for me.

Comment: @imsodin Its not collectibles its the firearms parts that's controversial. I kinda doubt it would have been closed it had been asking about something else like say freeze dried food